# joining vector to dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, join, vector, merge

I have dataframe with columns:

```
(Intercept) population urbanisation density temperature h_dev_index
0                  0         0          0      0           0
```

also I have vector of numbers:
k_koef

```
(Intercept)        population     urbanisation    density
-5.731845e-01      5.027081e-03   1.362376e-02 -4.130975e-04
```

I need to join one column to another:

```
    (Intercept) population    urbanisation   density         temperature h_dev_index
    0                  0           0            0             0           0
  -5.731845e-01 5.027081e-03  1.362376e-02  -4.130975e-04    NA          NA
```

How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turn the vector to dataframe and use `dplyr::bind_rows` :

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 5, e = 6)
k_koef <- c(a = 1.1, c = 4.5, e = 4.5)
dplyr::bind_rows(df, as.data.frame(t(k_koef)))

#    a  b   c  d   e
#1 1.0  2 4.0  5 6.0
#2 1.1 NA 4.5 NA 4.5
```

Comment: @ВладимирКузовкин Please provide a reproducible example. As shown in my answer it  works. I have a doubt that you actually don't have a dataframe but both of them are vectors. However, difficult to confirm that without you giving more information. Check `class(df)` and `class(k_koef)`.